# Where I can find database of samples of FFT coefficients for different musical instruments

Tags: synthesis

I'm experimenting with [AudioContext API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createPeriodicWave) and wonder where I can find data to create periodic wave imitating musical instuments.

For instance, here's how hammond-like organ can be imitated:
http://codepen.io/Clafou/pen/smdtl/

I do recognize how primitive is this approach but well, to have something to start with.

Comment: Do you mean Fourier coefficients as in, “the _n_-th harmonic has such and such amplitude”? As you remarked yourself: that would be rather too primitive to simulate any instrument convincingly at all. However, if you're actually talking about the whole result of a short-time DFT, then this is basically equivalent to using ordinary time-domain samples and calculating the FFT yourself. These will be much easier to come by than samples already in frequency-domain.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, yes, I meant the simplified approach (the n-th harmonic...)  but actually thank you for response.